VMConnect - You do not have the required permission to complete this task
Trying to use VMConnect to allow a user to connect to a virtual machine on a Hyper-V server.
As soon as they give the server name, the VMConnect client immediately informs them:

You do not have the required permissions to complete this task. Contact the administrator of the authorization policy for the computer '%s'.

For example:

I am the administrator of the authorization policy for the computer '%s'.  That error doesn't help me. Nor does it help other people who are getting the same error.
What change do i have to make to what authorization policy to allow users (or even domain administrators) to be able to connect (not even remotely manage; just connect) to a virtual machine using vmconnect?
What Have I Tried

run vmconnect6.3.exe as an administrator

Poking holes in the firewall of the Hyper-V server machine

netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI)" new enable=yes


in dcomcnfg COM Security, grant Local Access and Remote Access to me, Authenticated Users, and Domain Users,

in dcomcnfg COM Security, grant Local Launch, Remote Launch, Local Activation, Remote Activation to me, Authenticated Users and Domain Users

Add me, Everyone, and Domain Users to the Hyper-V Administrators group

in WMI Control security, grant Enable Account to me, Authenticated Users and Domain Users to the Root\CIMV2 namespace

in WMI Control security, grant Enable Account to me, Authenticated Users and Domain Users to the Root\virtualization namespace


Bonus Reading

Cannot connect to Hyper-V host Server 2016
Can I remote manage a Hyper-V Server that's running on Windows 8?
MSDN Blogs: Part 1 - Hyper-V Remote Management: You do not have the required permission to complete this task. Contact the administrator of the authorization policy for the computer ‘COMPUTERNAME’


This old post might be useful.
